# Next.js and Jest: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, next.js, babel-jest

I am working on a Next.js project using TypeScript and for testing I use Jest and React Testing Lib. However, I encounter a **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module** for components where I import **rehype-raw**.

As far as I understand this, Jest does not support ES6 so node_modules may need to be transformed. This can be configured using `transformIgnorePatterns`. For example if `rehype-raw` is causing this error using `"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!rehype-raw)/"]` should allow transformation of the `rehype-raw` but no other module.  And thus solve this error.

However, this does not work for me. But idk why and how I can solve this. No suggested solution I have found could solve this problem. I have attached my **error output**, **jest.config.js** and **babel.rc** file below.

**Error output**

```
 FAIL  test/pages/companies/[id].test.tsx                  
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    [...]

    Details:

    /path/frontend-job/node_modules/rehype-raw/index.js:7
    import {raw} from 'hast-util-raw'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      3 | import Image from 'next/image';
      4 | import { Remark } from 'react-remark';
    > 5 | import rehypeRaw from 'rehype-raw';
        | ^
      6 | import rehypeSanitize from 'rehype-sanitize';
      7 | import { logError } from '@utils/logger';
      8 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (components/markdown/JobMarkdown.tsx:5:1)
```

**jest.config.js**

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>[/\\\\](node_modules|.next)[/\\\\]'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!rehype-raw)/',
  ],
  watchPlugins: [
    'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
    'jest-watch-typeahead/testname',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Force mocks: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4262
    '@api/axios': '<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/axios.js',
    // Normal module aliases
    '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png)$': '<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '^@test/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './test/$1'),
    '^@test/faker/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './test/faker/$1'),
    '^@components/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './components/$1'),
    '^@pages/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './pages/$1'),
    '^@utils/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './utils/$1'),
    '^@api/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './api/$1'),
    '^@store/(.*)$': resolve(__dirname, './store/$1'),
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

**babel.rc**

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Next has already out-of-the-box support for Jest, I'd suggest you follow the steps [provided in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-the-rust-compiler).

Comment: I tried next/js as described in the docs and also extended the custom jest config, but I still get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: I think using https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31152#discussioncomment-1697047 I could solve this syntax error but some mocks are not working anymore

Comment: This thread has some discussion + code I've found valuable when the OP's issue happens for me: https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/635#issuecomment-956158474. Long story short, I just mock the ES6 modules that don't play nicely, where that's appropriate.

Comment: There was a bug in next/jest but it was fixed and everything works for me right now.

Comment: Can you post the solution if this works please? The docs do not give the fix

Answer (score 7):

Jest does not support ECMAScript Modules which is what `hast-util-raw` uses. Second problem; `transformIgnorePatterns` did not work too so below is the fix for myself with a Next.JS setup.

#### 1. Delete babel.rc

Delete your `babel.rc`. You can just use the below changes.

#### 2. Add moduleNameMapper

This fixes a different error where `parse5` can not be found. Required by `hast-util-raw`

```
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
  //...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'parse5/lib/parser/index.js':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/hast-util-raw/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/index.js',
  }
}
```

### 3. Add transformIgnorePatterns

Add `transformIgnorePatterns` however right **at the end**. As I said, this did not work adding directly into the config for som reason. I also had to add every package used by `hast-util-raw`. I am sure there is a better way to do this though :)

```
module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(rehype-raw|hast-util-raw|unist-util-position|unist-util-visit|unist-util-visit-parents|unist-util-is|hast-util-from-parse5|hastscript|property-information|hast-util-parse-selector|space-separated-tokens|comma-separated-tokens|vfile-location|web-namespaces|hast-util-to-parse5|zwitch|html-void-elements)/)'
  ]
})
```

---

My full config if anyone is interested...

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './'
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
  moduleDirectories: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/src/pages'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/.next/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/coverage',
    '<rootDir>/dist'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'react-markdown': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-markdown/react-markdown.min.js',
    'parse5/lib/parser/index.js':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/hast-util-raw/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/index.js'
  },
  resolver: '<rootDir>/.jest/resolver.js',
  clearMocks: true,
  testTimeout: 20000
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
// module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(rehype-raw|hast-util-raw|unist-util-position|unist-util-visit|unist-util-visit-parents|unist-util-is|hast-util-from-parse5|hastscript|property-information|hast-util-parse-selector|space-separated-tokens|comma-separated-tokens|vfile-location|web-namespaces|hast-util-to-parse5|zwitch|html-void-elements)/)'
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to understand is Next.js will tell Jest to not transform packages under `/node_modules` except those defined in their config file (the `transpilePackages` property).

It's a bit of a mess to add properly transform exclusions over this, but https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31152#discussioncomment-1697047 put me on the right track.

If you don't want to manually manage the array since it depends on `transpilePackages` on the Next.js side, I reused their logic at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/435eca3fc5b5dd23cad6cff43632bdcc777727d9/packages/next/src/build/jest/jest.ts#L156-L173 to transform both those from `transpilePackages` but also the ones needed for Jest to run properly.

Here the diff of my workaround:
https://github.com/inclusion-numerique/mediature/commit/cfe3ad85ab13d3f38d863afb8ee24b6995ae4e00

**I'm sorry to not put direct code on this post, it would make things unclear.**

Comment: This is great - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me was @rottitime. I noticed moving transformIgnorePatterns to the config object outside of the async function at the bottom does not work. For example, this will not work:

```js
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js'
 
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
})
 
// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/.next/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/coverage',
    '<rootDir>/dist'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(mui-tel-input)/)'
  ]
}

const exportConfig = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)())
});


export default exportConfig;
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you already use type:"module" in package.json?

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: did not work for me too. The change needs to be applied to jest config I think