# Next.js Cannot use import statement outside a module in third party library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jestjs, ts-jest

**Summary**

I'm using Next.js to create both API and and Frontend app. Frontend uses react. To unit testing I'm using `next/jest` preset and jest as an unit testing library. I'm using `@tenstack/react-query` to state management and when I want to test page, it throws an error. In tests where I'm using `jsdom` environment I add

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

in tests to API I'm using `babel-jest` that is default and no need anything

**error that throws**

```bash
    /path/to/project/node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/src/QueryClientProvider.tsx:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import * as React from 'react'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The error appers in test where I want to render page that uses `react-query`

**jest.config.js**

```js
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './'
});

const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$': 'ts-jest'
  }
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

**.babelrc**

```json
{
  "presets": ["next/babel","@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator"
  ]
}
```

I've tried [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916761/next-js-and-jest-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) but unfortunatelly it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved myself an issue by mocking library `@tenstack/react-query`. Here is an sample code

```js
jest.mock('@tanstack/react-query/src/QueryClientProvider', () => ({
  QueryClientProvider: ({ children }) => children
}));

jest.mock('@tanstack/react-query', () => ({
  QueryClient: jest.fn(),
  useQueryClient: jest.fn(),
  useQuery: jest.fn(),
  useMutation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    mutate: jest.fn(),
    isLoading: false
  })
}));
```